# Set up Wheel Emulation lock key with evdev

Tags: mouse-scroll, xinput, evdev

I have a trackball and I've just figured out how to enable wheel emulation with xinput. It's good to have the option, but it is a little painful having to hold down a button while scrolling. If possible, I'd like to map a key from my keyboard to toggle wheel emulation for my trackball. It doesn't seem like this behaviour is supported, but perhaps someone here knows of or has written a patch / hacked up script to accomplish it?

Thanks!